# Regular Expression exact count of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATION OF REFERENCED QUESTION because I already google this and test these solutions and after not founding appropriate answer I post this question

I need to validate some inputs that are like this:

```
first char always : 0

second char always: 1

and exactly 9 digits after that
```

e.g.

```
case 1:01123456789 => should match

case 2:`01123456789`0=> should not match but does match

case 3:123`01123456789`5985 => should not match but does match
```

I already using this pattern

```
/([0][1][0-9]{9})/g
```

but case 2 and 3 does match with this pattern too and only case 1 should be accepted

how can I achieve this?

[Using this tool to test the patterns](https://regex101.com/r/E7ex9t/1)

Comment: @SeanBright I made an edit to the question, thank you for notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use appropriate anchoring (`\b` in this case for 'word boundary'):

```
/\b01\d{9}\b/g
```

Comment: I put a link to the tool I use to test the pattern in my question